# Blender UV Editor Messed up 90 degrees

Tags: modeling

My blender UV Editor is messed up, Whenever I put a texture in UV editor the model in my 3D viewport has the texture flipped 90 degrees (see the examples below).
[image]

Any ideas on how I could fix this issue?
Also, I am very new at this so please be gentle with the explanation

Comment: go to edit mode in the 3D Viewport, and select the plane that appears rotated.  go to the UV editor and rotate the plane 90 degrees.  The UV editor doesn't know what "up" is in the 3D Viewport.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple problem but to understand it, you need to understand how UV mapping works.

Basically, you need to tell Blender how he should project the texture on your mesh and you do that by UV unwrapping your mesh.

If you mesh is a simple as a plane (which is the case here). You just select the plane (in edit mode) and press `U` and click on `Unwrap`. After that your mesh (the plane) will be projected on a flat surface and you can visualize how it was projected by going to the UV editor.

The problem here is that your plane have been unwrapped sideways :

[image]

To correct that, you can just go to edit mode, select your screen (the part that has the texture) and hit `U` and then `Unwrap`. It should give the result that you are looking for.

If it still appears sideways, you will need to go to the UV Editor (without exiting edit mode with only the screen selected). Hover you mouse in the UV editor and press `A` to select all and then `R` then `-90` to rotate your UV's by 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

You may get something like this after that :

[image]

You can correct this by adjusting your UV's. You can transform your UV's just the same way you transform things in the 3D viewport. Basically you just want the orange rectangle to fit your image texture so you can use `S` + `X`to scale along the X axis and `S` + `Y` to scale along the Y axis :

[image]

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you @mqbaka mqbaka

Comment: Glad I helped. If the answer solves your problem, you may mark it as accepted so that the topic is marked as solved.